# Alter the position of barcode in \begin{pspicture} within a rmarkdown document

Tags: miktex, r, rmarkdown, pst-barcode, barcodes

I'm trying to alter the position of a barcode in a document, but so far I have found nothing...

This is my **Rmd** file (with the YAML header between these two `---`)...

````
---
geometry: paperheight = 8cm, paperwidth = 12cm, margin = 0.5cm
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
fontsize: 10pt
header-includes:
  - \pagenumbering{gobble}
  - \usepackage{pst-barcode,pstricks-add}
params:
  barCodeNumber: 12345678
---

```{=latex}
\psset{unit=1cm}
\begin{pspicture}(0.0,0.0)(7.5,1.9)
    \psbarcode{`r params[["barCodeNumber"]]`}{width=0.6 height=0.3}{code128}
\end{pspicture}
```
````

... which I execute in R with `rmarkdown::render("C:/Users/tueftla/R/Test.Rmd")`. The result is a pdf with the barcode on position 1 - but I want to have the barcode at **position 2** (see image).

Can you please help me with this issue? Many thanks in advance.

[image: Desired barcode shift]